# Binding Winforms DataGridView to MembershipUserCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, datagridview

I'm trying to bind a DataGridView to a MembershipUserCollection but the grid refused to show any users even though there are records in the database.

according to my research on the internet I did the following:

```
MembershipUserCollection x = Membership.GetAllUsers();

gvUsers.DataSource = x;
```

Appreciate your Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the object you bind to needs to implement one of these interfaces

- `IList`
- `IListSource`
- `IBindingList`
- `IBindingView`

Whereas MembershipUserCollection only implements `ICollection`.

One solution would be to create a wrapper/adapter which implements one of these interfaces.

---

This might work, can't test it atm.

```
var collection = Membership.GetAllUsers();
var bindingList = new BindingList<MemberShipUser>();

// If it's only meant for display
bindingList.AllowNew = false;
bindingList.AllowRemove = false;
bindingList.AllowEdit = false;

foreach (MemberShipUser member in collection)
{
    bindingList.Add(member);
}
```

Comment: any hints on how to create this wrapper/adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's obvious but I had to make the minor tweak from MemberShipUser to MembershipUser.

Set the bindingList as the datasource for my datagrid and it worked beautifully!